# Payumoney activity indicator not showing iOS sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, payumoney

I have integrate payumoney framework in my project.
see below screenshot.

UIActivity indicator like below screenshot is not showing in my project.
Please help me how to debug this issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]